# In python get page with authentication

Tags: python, url, redirect

I have issue with getting page from site.
Them always send to page "login" when user non authenticated.
How i can do using python, login in one page and with redirect, using previous cookies get next web page?

Thanks.

For example, I login on site successfully :

```
import urllib2
import urllib

data = {}
data['name'] = 'user'
data['location'] = 'pass'
data['language'] = 'Python'
url_values = urllib.urlencode(data)
url = 'http://site/logon.action'
full_url = url + '?' + url_values
data = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)
```

But when I try other URL not "logon.action" i got message with redirect to logon page.

Comment: Question isn't clear.
Please follow this suggestions when writing down a question: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Sorry, add more info

Comment: where dou you redirect user? Please show that part of your code.

Comment: There is part of code :) I just in the next string replace URL and get http request with redirect.

Comment: maybe you should use Session http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Comment: As you suggest, the problem is most likely that the site is giving you a cookie after authentication, but you aren't providing that on the next request - so it asks you to login again. Suggest you use a higher-level library like requests which has the idea of a session http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects and automatically propagates cookies through the session.